# Good CMS (preferable java-based) to integrate with grails app

Tags: grails, content-management-system

We have grails application that is damn good. Grails application will be run under tomcat/jetty. I'm looking for a good (preferable java-based) CMS which could be deployed to same webserver and integrated with our application. Our app provides some data (xml/json) and we need that CMS display this data on some static pages (I'm thinking of java-script gadgets that just connects to our grails same-host-same-port-different-context app).

If someone know some other techniques how to easily embed data into CMS static pages - would be nice to hear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Weceem CMS](http://www.weceem.org)

Depending on what features you need for your CMS, **Weceem** could fit to your requirements. It is a grails plugin itself (with advantages like being unobtrusive).
Be aware that currently it is not compatible with Nimble and Commentable plugins (will be in version 0.9).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to play with it, but [Alfresco Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/alfresco) allows you to connect to Alfresco.  I imagine it's more of a document management integration at this point, but Alfresco can handle WCM as well.

Answer (score -1):

You ought to find the answer at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

It's the first I would recommend to anyone looking for a CMS. Use the wizard, select the features you want, get details of matching CMS and make your comparison then choice.